# Can the ender dragon see you in minecraft when you have a potion of invisibility

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am planning on fighting soon and just wondering if a potion of invisibilty would be a good thing to bring along.

Answer (score 6):

The Ender Dragon is not influenced by invisibility potions. Source: I just tested it in a creative world.

This is true for 1.8.3. I haven't tested any other versions.

Comment: I just tried this in 1.12.2. It was as if the ender dragon could see me from the get go, magic bombs, head butts, the whole nine yards. So, invisibility potions do not seem to help, unless maybe you take off all your armour and go against it with nothing but fists....

Comment: OK, so I tried again wearing no armour, and the dragon can't see you! Useful if you want to build something like a pillar or stairs. BUT once I started hitting the crystals the dragon found me quick and without armour I didn't last long.

Answer (score 1):

The dragon doesn't dive bomb you when invisibility is in affect. However I've noticed it will throw magic bombs and dive bomb the last location arrows are shot from.

Way to win. Invisibility. Feather fall. Make a pillar. Shot crystals from pillar. Make way to enclosed crystals and destroy. Then kill dragon with arrows slowly.

Answer (score 1):

The Ender Dragon can't see you until you shoot arrows at her or hit her. My advice would be to shoot her as quickly as possible and then get out of that spot fast because she's about to throw you up in the sky or throw fireballs at you right there.

Answer (score 1):

In a way all the previous answers are right. The dragon cannot see you if you have the invisibility buff, provided you are wearing no armour and do nothing aggressive. As soon as you do anything that harms the dragon, including hitting the crystals, it will track you, and you will not last long without armour.

I found that at least some of the time if you destroy the crystals using redstone circuitry and TNT while invisible the dragon seems to fail to notice you. Maybe the few seconds to ignite the TNT is long enough to get away from the scene.

So, the way forward is to go into the end wearing no armour and with the invisibility buff. Do whatever you need to do to gain access to the crystals, mining obsidian, making a pillar or whatever. Just avoid hitting anything! When you are ready put on your armour and then the fun starts.